# MVC Mailer layout is not rendering any html other thatn the RenderBody method

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvcmailer

Hi I am using MVC Mailer to manage creating and sending emails in my application. It will create and send the email fine but any html I insert inside the body in the layout is not in the email.

**Mailer**

```
public class Mailer : MailerBase, IMailer
{
    public aMailer()
    {
        MasterName = "_EmailLayout";
    }

    public virtual MvcMailMessage RequestAccess(RequestAccessViewModel viewmodel)
    {
        ViewData.Model = viewmodel;

        return Populate(x =>
        {
            x.Subject = "RequestAccess for Data";
            x.ViewName = "RequestAccess";
            x.To.Add("AppTeam@groups.hp.com");
            x.From = new MailAddress(viewmodel.Email);
        });
    }
}
```

I am setting it to use _EmailLayout here, I cahnged the name after seeing that there was an issue with naming it _Layout because it would conflict with any other files named _Layout.

**_EmailLayout**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Mailer</h1>
    @RenderBody()

    Thanks
</body>
```

The contents of the H1 tag or "Thanks" are not in the email

**Access.cshtml**

```
<h3>"This is a Application email." </h3>
<p>@Model.Message</p>
<br/>
<p>Regards</p>
<p>@Model.Name</p>
<p>Business Area: @Model.BusinessArea</p>
```

**Email Source**

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"><title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <p> Hi jeff test,</p>
    <br>
    <p>Thank you for your enquiry about the Application.</p>
    <br>

</body>
```

Has anyone come across this issue before? When I debug my application I can see that it is going into the _EmailLayout but I don't know why the HTML in that files is not rendered.

Comment: I was getting the same thing when the Layout view path was incorrect (missing a '/').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting the following issue on the [github page for MVC Mailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/120) 
Changing the layout code to this fixed the problem

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  Mailer

  @RenderBody()

  Thanks

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why this fixed the problem but it did.